# Execute command on LINUX via PUTTY from Windows

Tags: windows, ssh, shell, putty, telnet

I want to open a putty session (SSH) from command line and immediately execute on the remote machine a specific command.

Something like:

```
putty.exe -ssh user@host -pw pass123 < "cd /some/directory; ll"
```

But this doesn't work.
Is it possible?

Comment: YES :D (i need to write more characters to add this comment. Done).

Comment: FYI, recent versions of Windows 10 have a native OpenSSH client that can be installed, and would probably be easier to work with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Putty also provides plink.

Usage example:

```
plink -ssh user@host -pw password echo "hi"
```

Also I suggest you to use **SSH-KEY** instead of password. It makes your work easier and safer. Look at ***Pageant*** and ***Putty Key Generator***. More information about keys: https://www.digitalocean.com/docs/droplets/how-to/add-ssh-keys/create-with-putty/